# How to use the "Locals" window in VBA IDE

Tags: ms-access, vba, ide

When I'm coding VBA in Access 2003, I keep the Immediate window visible and I use Debug.Print and Stop to solve my challenges.  But I've never known how to get help from the "Locals" window.  I understand what's in there for the most part.  But it usually seems like I'd have to dig around for the item I want, and it could take a while to find it in all those folded structures.

(And "Locals" doesn't bring up anything from the built-in VBA help files.  Maybe I'm missing a file ...)

I bet I could start using Locals, if I knew what it's good for in a practical way.  Do do you have an explanation or anecdote that would clue me in?

Comment: I accepted the 1 answer and tried out "Locals" again.  I see what the stumbling block has been.  I didn't realize that once I locate the needed variable in Locals, that view will be preserved for the next time the sub/function is called.  That is, the IDE will retain that viewable spot in the nested structures that are exposed through "Locals".

Comment: So if I place one breakpoint and F5 along, I can see the relevant variables change in a coherent fashion.  Which is incredibly handy.  Of course if the view weren't preserved, life would be miserable (per my earlier ignorance).

Comment: Really, you need to start using breakpoints for debuggin. The Locals window displays the values of variables without having to hover over them or query them in the Immediate window. That said, I don't use it, because the values I'm most interested in (such as SQL strings) are often just to long to be usably displayed in the Locals window. You should also muck about with Watches, as these can be even more useful, since you can define them to break on certain conditions.

Comment: Yes David, I use Breakpoints very often (though I mentioned Stop, which I use seldom).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Locals provides a couple of benefits: You can F8 through the code and watch how a variable changes by looking at the locals window as opposed to issuing debug.print statements or hovering over the variables.  You can see the contents of an array a heck of a lot quicker than issuing lbound and ubound and a bunch of other statements to check values.  Not just arrays either, but any complex data structure such as a custom class module.

Comment: I recently learned to keep an eye on the "Variables" window when using NetBeans/XDebug for PHP. Your answer is telling me VBA "Locals" is the simple equivalent. That's definitely the handle I was looking for.

Comment: A week later:  I am reaching for Locals naturally.  Thanks again.

Comment: 4.5 years later:  Guess I should have kept at it.  New lessons at http://stackoverflow.com/q/22673118/122139.