# Expose an array in MS Access - equivalent of var_dump()

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I have an array populated in VBA, and dont'cha know, it's really an array of arrays.  So I want the equivalent of PHP's `var_dump()` function.  Such a beautiful tool (and here, right now, I am discovering people want its equivalent for a bunch of languages.)

The VBA Locals window lets me wade deep into the Object Model, but I can't poke around in my array.  No help there.

The only answer I've ever known is to design `For` loops and send each one-line result out to the good ol' one-line Immediate window.  I'll have to explicitly declare the array in every aspect.  Whereas `var_dump()` is self-discovering -- demands nothing, returns instant results.

I know <strike>I won't get that, and I know the answer to my question is "Forget it"</strike> **(happy revision)** ... but has anyone discovered something to help the VBA pilgrim?

Comment: Do you want to print out the whole array, or what?  What kind of output are you looking for?

Comment: Yep, the whole array.  Due to the "heavily synchronous" nature of VBA, and the one-line-only design of Immediate, it seems improbable.  But that's what I dream about.

Comment: Discovering how to leverage the Locals Window would count for a lot.

Comment: You can put multiple lines together at one in the immediate window if you put a `:` between them

Comment: How is your object delcared? that seems weird that you can't look at everything about it in the locals window? maybe it is declared out of the scope of you sub/function? you can add it to a watch window then.

Comment: @Brad -- use of `:` is mildly relevant but of course does not address the core issue.  So, a Watch Window, you say?  I might be accepting that, was it to be posted as an answer and was I to see it helpfully in action.  No, there is no scoping issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your array to a `Watch`

[image: Right click and select watch]

[image: Add to watch OK]

[image: Expand object it watch]

Comment: I like this idea and have added a watch to a query variable, however it's not able to be expanded after running the sub. Can you please explain how it's working to be filled with data/monitored? It says Type Recordset

Answer (score 3):

This is very simplistic, but might get you started:

```
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print Dump(Array("a", "n",  _
                     Array("1", Array("hello", "there"), _
                     5), 77, 88, 100))
End Sub



Function Dump(v, Optional level As Long = 0)
Dim i As Long, s As String
    s = ""
    If TypeName(v) Like "*()" Then
        For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
            If TypeName(v(i)) Like "*()" Then
                s = s & Space(level * 4) & i & ": [Array]" & vbLf
                s = s & Dump(v(i), level + 1)
            Else
                s = s & Space(level * 4) & i & ": " & v(i) & vbLf
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    Dump = s
End Function
```

**EDIT:** @Brad's Watch window suggestion is probably the easiest approach if you want to be able to navigate the output.

Comment: Really exciting your answer, in a proof-of-concept kind of way.  Agree with you Brad's answer is what I want, on a more practical level.  I hope to test and upvote both suggestions this evening.

Comment: It seems to need some finishing. `TypeName()` is new to me and isn't quite correctly in place; a subscript error (hey, we're talking arrays). What's exciting is the idea of using a diagnostic `Sub` while in break mode. Heck, I've done that before, but it seems new and thrilling at the moment. It must be Friday. Anyhoo, THANKS much.