# VBA- Ubound Lbound error

Tags: vba, excel

I need help plz I wrote the code below, but it throw up error 13 type mismatch at the line "For i = LBound(header, 2) To UBound(header, 2)". Where is the problem?

```
Function Get_Header_Dico(ByVal header As Variant, _
                         ByVal header_line As Long) As Dictionary

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim headerDict      As Dictionary

    Set headerDict = New Dictionary

    For i = LBound(header, 2) To UBound(header, 2)
        If Not headerDict.Exists(header(header_line, i)) Then
            headerDict.Add header(header_line, i), i
        Else
            MsgBox "Please check data header, there is a duplicate"
            End
        End If
    Next i

    Set Get_Header_Dico = headerDict
End Function
```

I am trying to compare 2 workbooks. Here is the calling code:

```
Sub Find_Differences()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim data1, data2
    Dim header As Dictionary, data1_Dico As Dictionary, data2_Dico As Dictionary
    Dim different_Dico As Dictionary
    Dim key, tmp, result
    Dim transaction_Type As String, ISIN As String, NAV_Date As String, value_Date As String, nature As String, amount As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim sBook As String

If Workbooks.Count < 2 Then
MsgBox "Erreur: Un seul fichier est ouvert" & vbCr & _
"Ouvrir un 2eme fichier et exécuter le macro"
Exit Sub
End If

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
For Each wb2 In Workbooks
If wb2.Name <> wb1.Name Then Exit For
Next

ReDo1:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
sBook = Application.InputBox(prompt:= _
"Comparer ce fichier (" & wb1.Name & ") avec...?", _
Title:="Compare to what workbook?", _
Default:=wb2.Name, Type:=2)
If sBook = "False" Then Exit Sub
If Workbooks(sBook) Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Fichier: " & sBook & " n'est pas ouvert."
GoTo ReDo1
Else
Set wb2 = Workbooks(sBook)
End If

    Set header = Get_Header_Dico(data1, 1)

    Set data1_Dico = New Dictionary
    For i = 2 To UBound(data1, 1)
        transaction_Type = data1(i, header("Transaction Type"))
        ISIN = data1(i, header("ISIN Code"))
        NAV_Date = Format(data1(i, header("NAV Date")), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        value_Date = Format(data1(i, header("Value Date")), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        nature = data1(i, header("Investment Type"))
        If nature = "Unit" Then
            amount = Format(data1(i, header("Share Nb.")), "#0.0000")
        ElseIf nature = "Amount" Then
            amount = Format(data1(i, header("Fund Amount (Client Cur.)")), "#0.0000")
        End If

        key = transaction_Type & "#" & ISIN & "#" & NAV_Date & "#" & value_Date & "#" & nature & "#" & amount
        If Not data1_Dico.Exists(key) Then
            data1_Dico.Add key, i
        End If

    Next i

    Set header = Get_Header_Dico(data2, 1)

    Set data2_Dico = New Dictionary
    For i = 2 To UBound(data2, 1)
        transaction_Type = data2(i, header("S/R type"))
        ISIN = data2(i, header("Fund share code"))
        NAV_Date = Format(data2(i, header("Pricing Date")), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        value_Date = Format(data2(i, header("Value Date")), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        nature = data2(i, header("Nature"))
        If nature = "Unit" Then
            amount = Format(data2(i, header("Quantity")), "#0.0000")
        ElseIf nature = "Amount" Then
            amount = Format(data2(i, header("Net amount")), "#0.0000")
        End If

        key = transaction_Type & "#" & ISIN & "#" & NAV_Date & "#" & value_Date & "#" & nature & "#" & amount
        If Not data2_Dico.Exists(key) Then
            data2_Dico.Add key, i
        End If
    Next i

    Set different_Dico = New Dictionary
    For Each key In data1_Dico.Keys
        If Not data2_Dico.Exists(key) Then
            different_Dico.Add key, key
        End If
    Next key

    ReDim result(1 To different_Dico.Count, 0 To 5)
    i = 0
    For Each key In different_Dico.Keys
        tmp = Split(key, "#")
        i = i + 1
        For j = 0 To UBound(tmp)
            result(i, j) = tmp(j)
        Next j
    Next key

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Differences")
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(result, 1), UBound(result, 2) + 1) = result
    End With

    Set different_Dico = New Dictionary
    For Each key In data2_Dico.Keys
        If Not data1_Dico.Exists(key) Then
            different_Dico.Add key, key
        End If
    Next key

    ReDim result(1 To different_Dico.Count, 0 To 5)
    i = 0
    For Each key In different_Dico.Keys
        tmp = Split(key, "#")
        i = i + 1
        For j = 0 To UBound(tmp)
            result(i, j) = tmp(j)
        Next j
    Next key

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Differences")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A" & lastRow + 2).Resize(UBound(result, 1), UBound(result, 2) + 1) = result
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Differences").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: It would appear that the `header` value you are passing is not an array.

Comment: `header` must not be an array. Put `Debug.Print TypeName(header)` before the offending line and see what you get.

Comment: Try putting the line "If TypeName(header) = "Range" Then header = header.Value" before the line that throws the error.

Comment: It didn't work! How can I correct it?

Comment: What did the `Debug.Print TypeName(header)` print? Also -- what is the calling code? The bug might lie there -- you aren't passing what you think you are passing. Also, my last suggestion did have a minor typo. It should have read `If TypeName(header) = "Range"` (without the leading quote mark)

Comment: The variable `data1` is completely uninitialized when you get to the line `Set header = Get_Header_Dico(data1, 1)` -- so of course it is empty. What do you expect `data1` to be?

Comment: It'd to be a table, I think I initialized it in the line "For i = 2 To UBound(data1, 1)
        transaction_Type = data1(i, header("Transaction Type"))..."?

Comment: That line isn't of the form `data1 = ` -- you *never* assign anything to `data1`. Also -- that line is *after* the function call that throws the error. You need to put data in `data1` before you try to construct a dictionary based on it.

Comment: The name "header" suggests that these are column labels. Where do the strings like "ISIN Code" etc. come from? In other words -- just where is `Get_Header_Dico` supposed to get the headers from? That function can't read your mind. If they are drawn from the workbook, assign the values in the appropriate range to `data1`before invoking the function.

Comment: But I need to generate the code to use it for numerous workbooks, that's why I don't assign the range value

Comment: If you know ahead of time what headers you want -- why pass anything to `Get_Header_Dico`? Just initialize the dictionary with these predetermined headers. If you don't know them ahead of time -- where do they come from? If they come from the workbooks -- figure out how to extract them. Perhaps you could post another question if you don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming that `header` will be a variant array; this isn't always true and, as [John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman) pointed out, you would do well to check the type.

This is a common error, and the underlying cause is:

**Passing an Excel Range object into a variant parameter in an Excel VBA function does *not* cast the incoming data to a variant data type.**

Yes, we know that the expected behaviour of the 'cast' is that an object will populate a variant with it's default property, and the default property property of a range is the `.Value` variant - but the result you actually get is that your 'variant' is an Excel Range.

So your variant `header` contains a reference to an object.

Now there are some functions - UBound() and LBound() spring to mind - which expect to see an array and **will** automatically cast the range's default `.Value` property as a variant array. But...

**If you've passed in a single-cell range, the `.Value` property of the range isn't an array.**

... and, for a single-cell range, it's a scalar variant; the type is a string or number or datetime type inferred from the cell's `.NumberFormat` property, and any functions which expect an array will throw a type error when they get that. Yes, UBound() and LBound() spring to mind, again: they'll work just fine, right up until the day you pass in a single-cell range.

Other things in a range will break 'downstream' functions that can cope with a simple grid of data from the spreadsheet: I'm guessing that you've got the most common example, a single cell; but an uninitialised `Nothing` object variable of type Range might just get far enough into the code to raise a Type error, too: as will a non-contiguous range (an array of arrays, each item corresponding to the .value properties of the range's .Areas collection).

If we're lucky other 'Stackers will comment and list even more exotic examples; and quite possibly, mundane examples that I've never heard of and would otherwise discover when my own code halts exactly where yours did today.

So the answer to your question is to check the incoming parameter, almost exactly as John Coleman suggested, and then populate an internal variable with your data:

```
Dim arrData As Variant

'If TypeOf header IS Excel.Range Then ' replaced by 'TypeName', which is more robust

If TypeName(header) = "Range" Then

    If header.Areas(1).Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Redim arrData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        arrData(1, 1) = header.Areas(1).Value2
    Else
        arrData = header.Areas(1).Value2
    End If

Else

    If Instr(TypeName(header),"(") > 1 Then 'This is more reliable than IsArray()
        arrData = header
    Else
        Redim arrData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        arrData(1, 1) = header
    End If

End If

' ...And run arrData through your code, instead of 'header'
```

*Almost* exactly as John suggested: searching the 'TypeName' for brackets is a more robust way of detecting an array than using varType.

You would also be well advised to run `IsError()` on the contents of any variant obtained from an Excel Range: once imported into VBA, formula errors in an range are intractable - no VBA function or operator can handle them.

And the moral of the story is:

**Writing a function that takes data from the worksheet always involves more defensive coding than you expected.**

Let us know how you get on!

Comment: Thank you but I got User-defined type not defined on the line "Function Get_Header_Dico(ByVal header As Variant, _
                         ByVal header_line As Long) As Dictionary". Where is the problem?

Comment: I also got error 91 on the line "If TypeOf header Is Excel.Range Then"

Comment: You get an unknown type error at `Function Get_Header_Dico(ByVal header As Variant, _ ByVal header_line As Long) As Dictionary` ? Your VBA project doesn't know what a 'Dictionary' is: go to the 'Tools' menu, open 'references', and create a reference to the Windows Scripting Runtime - that's the library you need for a reference to the `Scripting.Dictionary` object.

Comment: Error 91 is 'Object variable not set' - my guess is that you are sometimes succeeding in getting a variant into `header`, and `TypeOf` only works on objects... Try `If TypeName(header) = "Range" Then` instead of my original suggestion.

Comment: I did as you wrote then the line "arrData(1, 1) = header" is marked empty

Comment: **The line "arrData(1, 1) = header" is marked empty**   That's a useful debugging clue - you're passing an empty cell, or an zero-length string, or  `Null`, or something completely unexpected that isn't an Excel.Range object at all.

Comment: So I need to change the range object or something? Because it's not working at all

Comment: No, you need to **inspect** it. When you know what it is, you will know how to handle it.  Run `TypeName()` on it, use breakpoints and inspect it in the [Locals Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241343/how-to-use-the-locals-window-in-vba-ide), A good basic tutorial for that is [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wn4yszixWyc)  - **and, above all, you need to learn how to use the [Watch Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031323/checking-the-values-of-public-variables-in-excel-vba-locals-window-alternative) .**

Comment: I got type mismatch on the line "For i = 2 To UBound(data1, 1)"

Comment: Inspect the variable `data` in a Watch or in the Locals window. When you know what it is, you will know how to handle it.

Comment: @shinpencil I don't think you're looking for the right sort of assistance: Stack Overflow can give you tips and comments on your code, but your problems are emerging from **the process of debugging code**: whatever I tell you here, It'll just move you along another point of failure which you won't be able to analyse, understand, and fix. There are good tutorials online that will help you use the Visual Basic IDE (Integrated Development Environment) and the 'Watch' window effectively; but I think you need to get class-based or one-on-one training on the basic principles of coding and debugging.

Comment: Anyone else noticed that range to array stopped working in Excel VBA? It's May 2023 and the macro that has worked so far (last time a month ago) now gives me Type Mismatch Error for UBoud and LBound.

`header.Areas(1).Cells.Count` = 63

`arrData = header.Areas(1).Value2` gives me Type Mismatch Error, too!